# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError is being reported even when using redirect_to and return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

I am getting this error

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError: Render and/or redirect were called 
multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render 
OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect 
nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an 
action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) 
and return"
```

Below you can find the controler, model and the view

This is the model (app/models/upload_file.rb)

```
class UploadFile

  def self.save(uploadData)
    @success = true;

    begin
      name = uploadData.original_filename
      directory = 'public/data'
      # create the file on the server
      path = File.join(directory, name)
      # write the file
      File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(uploadData.read) }

    rescue
      @success = false;
    end

    return @success;
  end

  def cleanup
    #Borrar el archivo una vez se haya procesado (ojo con los que se analizan pero tienen errores, tambien se deben borrar)
  end
end
```

This is the relevant part of the controller(app/controllers/employees_controller.rb)

```
  def upload
    add_breadcrumb 'Cargar Archivo', :employees_upload_path
    render 'employees/uploadFile'
  end

  def uploadFile
    @exito = UploadFile.save(params['upload']['datafile'])

    if (@exito)
      redirect_to employees_uploadValidate_path and return
    end
  end
```

This is the view (app/views/employees/uploadFile.html.erb)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateFileName() {
        var fileName ;
        var valido ;

        fileName = document.getElementById("upload_datafile").value ;

        //Revisar que el archivo tenga la extension esperada
        valido = (fileName !== undefined) && (fileName.length >= 5) && (endsWith(fileName.toUpperCase(),".XLS") || endsWith(fileName.toUpperCase(),".XLSX")) ;

        if (!valido) {
            alert('Debe elegir un archivo de EXCEL (XLS o XLSX)')
        }

        return valido ;
    }

    function endsWith(str, suffix) {
        return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    }
</script>
<div class="left p-breadcrumbs">
  <%= render_breadcrumbs :separator => ' > ' %>
</div>
<div class="row margin-row">
  <div class="separador"></div>
  <div class="row small-12 centered">
    <div class="small-8 columns">
      <h1>Cargar Archivo</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row small-12 centered">
    <%= form_tag({:action => 'uploadFile'}, :multipart => true, :onsubmit => 'return validateFileName();') do %>
        <p><label for="upload_file">Seleccione el archivo a cargar:</label>
          <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
        <%= submit_tag 'Subir Archivo' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my routes.rb I have the following lines

```
  get 'employees/upload'
  post 'employees/uploadFile'
  get 'employees/uploadValidate'
```

I don't understand why if I have a redirect_to and return is causing a `DoubleRenderError`

In fact the error is being reported at exactly that line

```
redirect_to employees_uploadValidate_path and return
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: @YanFoto the error is being reported at redirect_to employees_uploadValidate_path and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that **not following the Ruby/Rails convention** of using `underscore_case` for the name of the **methods** and **views** of the controller was causing the problem.

To solve this I refactor `uploadFile` method to `upload_file` and renamed the view to match this convention also. I apply the same to the `upload_validate` method and view and this solved the problem.

I post this links in case you want to know more about this subject

- [The Unofficial Ruby Usage Guide](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml)
- [RubyStyleGuide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)
- [RailsStyleGuide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here. I believe the error is happening at you `upload` method. If we take a closer look there, seems like `add_breadcrumb` method is redirecting you somewhere using the path, and after, it still calls the `render` method.

Comment: Finks, breadcrumb does not redirect, it creates a link to that page to allow navigation between different options